# Clock frozen in the notification bar

Tags: notification-bar, clock

Every once in a while, my Asus TF300T freezes for a bit and some apps crash. I notice that when this happens, the clock freezes in the status bar. For example the time in the notification bar will be 12:25 but the Clock app will show 12:28. This issue can easily be resolved simply be restating my device, but if I am the middle of working, I do not have time to wait 10-15 minutes for it to start back up again. Everything else functions as normal, such as buttons and notifications. My device is not rooted.

In this screenshot you can see the clock says the correct time and the frozen time in the upper right corner

[image]

How can I "unfreeze" the clock in the notification bar **without** restarting my device?

Comment: Do you have root? `pkill com.android.systemui`

Comment: @aureljared No unfortunately do not have root.